# Can the direct product of nontrivial groups $A\times B$ ever be isomorphic to a free group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, free-groups

Can the direct product of nontrivial groups $A\times B$ ever be isomorphic to a free group?

Let's say that for two groups $A$ and $B$ we have that $A\times B \cong F_n$ where $F_n$ is the free group of rank $n$.

I found [in this paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-00888-2_6?noAccess=true) that any group isomorphic to a free group is itself free.

Assuming that is correct, then $A\times B = F_m$ for some $m\in \mathbb{N}$. In fact, since free groups are unique up to isomorphism (which preserves rank), I believe then $A\times B = F_n$. However, I'm not sure what exactly this would mean. Is this even possible?

Elements of $A\times B$ would look like ordered pairs (e.g. $(1,2)$), whereas (for example) elements of $F_2 =\langle a,b \rangle$ would look like $a^2b^5$, etc. So, I don't see how a group whose elements consist of ordered pairs could ever be equal to a group whose elements are not ordered pairs.

Of course, the obvious counterexample occurs if either $A$ or $B$ are trivial, in which case (say $B=\{1\}$) we have $A\times B= A\times \{1\}=A=F_n$.

Assuming then that $A$ and $B$ are nontrivial, can $A\times B$ ever be isomorphic to a free group?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, because elements of $A$ and $B$ commute with each other. (Note I am identifying $A$ and $B$ with $A\times\{1_B\}$ and $\{1_A\}\times B$ respectively.) However in a free group the only elements which commute are powers of a common element. Any power of a mixed element $(a,b)$ where $a,b$ are nontrivial, stays mixed because $a$ and $b$ must have infinite order. Moreover any power of $(a,1_B)$ stays in $A$ and any power of $(1_A,b)$ stays in $B$. Thus elements of $A$ and $B$ cannot be powers of a common element.